# Navigation Drawer Activity. Do I need more than 1?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I'm a little lost on how to use the Navigation Drawer Activity. I'm not sure as to how to use it, I created one in android studio but it's given me several xml files
[image: a list of the files created]

So I'm not sure what each one is for. I don't think the https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html has anything on it. (A bit daunted by it)

What does each file do and which one do I put my main content in?
Please do ask any questions you have and I'll do my best to answer them.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a navigation drawer activity gives 4 XML Layout files i.e

1. **Base layout file** - It is the base Layout file which contains **< android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout >** and **< android.support.design.widget.NavigationView >** and an **< include >** tag to include **App Bar layout file** in this layout which in turn includes **main content Layout file**. 
   In your case - **activity_character_sheety_activity.xml** is main Layout File
2. **App Bar layout File** - This file contains the layout for **ActionBar/Toolbar** and an **< include >** tag which includes **Main content layout file** in this layout.
   In your case - app_bar_character_sheety_activity.xml is AppBar Layout File.
3. **Navigation Drawer Header Layout File** - This file is used for the setting the layout of header of the navigation drawer and is used by **< android.support.design.widget.NavigationView >**'s **headerLayout** attribute.
   In your case - **nav_header_character_sheety_activity.xml** is the header file.
4. **Main content Layout File** - It is the **main** layout of your Activity. All the layouts related to the operations of your activity goes in here.

In your case - **content_character_sheety_activity.xml** is main content file and you should put your **MAIN CONTENT** in this file.